# What is the effect of sound frequency on hearing?

Tags: hearing, ear, frequency, eardrum, soundwaves

We all know that humans can tolerate lower frequencies at high volumes better than higher frequencies. In fact, for particularly low frequencies, high SPL is needed just for it to be audible.

What’s the difference between low and high frequencies for the ear?

If the decibels are equal, does low frequency sound cause the same amount of total hearing damage as other frequencies? If not, how much less damage does it cause? What is the maximum safe threshold for lower frequencies?

By low frequency, I am referring to the range of 16-100Hz, which is the range of most commercial subwoofers.

I am aware of people with 150db+ car audio systems, who are not deaf or hearing impaired. With regular sound, this would be as loud as a gunshot and constant exposure will surely cause significant damage. Many people in those communities seem to think bass is safe at loud volumes. However, I have not found any research to support or counter this argument.

[Clearly, low frequency sound affects hearing differently than high frequency sound.](http://rsos.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/1/2/140166)

---

This is different from https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/10132 because I am specifically asking the difference in hearing damage of frequencies. **I am aware that high frequency damages high frequency hearing and so on, but surely, it will also damage other frequencies of hearing and the rate of damage is different.** It also does not account other types of hearing damage such as tinnitus. The answer to the other question does not contain scientific sources either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which deteriorates hearing faster; treble or bass?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/10132/which-deteriorates-hearing-faster-treble-or-bass)

Comment: To put this VERY short -- I don't have time to reference this but my understanding is as you lose hair cells, you lose the ability to hear higher frequencies.  The damage is caused by simply high dB noise, what pitch of sound is lost is not directly related to the type of sound your exposed to (i.e low freq over exposure does not cause low freq sensitivity to decrease).  It's more of a general damage to the entire organ with the higher freq's being lost first.  There are GREAT youtube videos on this BTW!

Comment: For this to be answerable, especially if you want *scientific sources*, you need to define *damage*.

Comment: @Mike-DHSc I think your understanding is incorrect. A high level sound with a narrow bandwidth will cause a narrow hearing loss. It won't perfectly match the frequency of the sound since as I explain in my [other answer](https://health.stackexchange.com/a/10169/55) sounds spreads out a little in the cochlea.

Comment: At Mike-DHSc, @StrongBad: Both of you have the power to VTC. Do you disagree with this being a duplicate? A site strongly depends on community moderation, and we are deeply lacking this.

Comment: @Narusan-in-coma the OP says it is not a dupe and seems receptive to trying to improve the question. I think it is nicer to work with a new user to make the question work than cast a quick VTC, try to convince the user that we are not mean and that they should but the effort into improving the question, and then get enough support to reopen the question.

Comment: @StrongBad In general I agree with you for questions that are off topic, I am of the opinion that duplicate questions can’t be „fixed“ though, **unless** the dupe is not what the OP meant. I apologise for not having seen the edit - which makes the question not a dupe anymore - and I will try to edit the post to make it clear for me and other users like me who‘s vice is not to read posts carefully enough.

Comment: @OP I have edited your question slightly. The biggest change is that your question is now also addressing general difference between low and high frequency for the  ear. I am hoping that an answer for this will also account for hearing damage and help you, us and future users to better grasp the difference between frequencies. If you disagree with my edit, please revert it or [edit] the question yourself. // I don’t think the question is a dupe, and I misunderstood or read over part of your questions when I thought of that. I apologise.

Comment: Not able to take time to look this up further however after reading your other post I think you're mixing up the area of the cochlea that's triggered by higher frequency sounds. It a distal to proximal loss would also support this. Will find research later. However you may indeed be correct just not convinced yet! lol